# Trying to parse a large text file saved as an std::string

Tags: c++, parsing, stl

I have a text file that I have to read in and extract data from parameters that belong to key words. This text file I am reading in is a lookup table to load in other files. I have read this file into memory through a file stream and saved it as an `std::string`. The complete text file is now saved in my class as a private member variable `std::string` type. I am calling a private function within my class passing in this text file as one string. This function is to parse the file looking for keywords and then extract the data from them. Also, some key words show up more then once and I need the count of each occurrence.

Here is what my txt file looks like.

```
: This is a comment.

HEADER[AudioBookReader v1.0]
TITLE[Gulliver's Travel]
AUTHOR[Jonathan Swift]
YEAR[1726]
CHAPTER_COUNT[39]

TABLE_OF_CONTENTS

INTRO[intro]  

SECTION[Part I. A Voyage To Lilliput]
CHAPTER[gt_1_01] 
CHAPTER[gt_1_02]
: more CHAPTERs

SECTION[Part II. A Voyage To Brobdingnag]
CHAPTER[gt_2_01]
CHAPTER[gt_2_02]
: more CHAPTERs

SECTION[Part III. A Voyage To Laputa, Balnibarbi, Luggnagg, Glubbdubdrib, And Japan]
CHAPTER[gt_3_01]
CHAPTER[gt_3_02]
CHAPTER[gt_3_03]
: more CHAPTERs and SECTIONs


OUTRO[NONE]         : This is here as an example if there is none it can be 
                    : omitted or use the tag NONE inside the parameter braces. 

END                 : This tag represents the end of the file anything after
                      will not get parsed, as you can see I did not use a comment.
```

All capital words are Tags or Keywords. Anything inside the braces is data needed. Anything after a colon ":" on that line is to be skipped, also anything after the END tag is to be disregarded and the parsing is complete. Most keywords have data associated with them and in most cases a string of text is what I need.

Only the first five Tags that have data have one instance. There are only two tags that do not have any data associated with them, `TABLE_OF_CONTENTS` and `END`. The only property of `TABLE_OF_CONTENTS` is to represent we have reached the beginning of the text part of the book. The rest of the tags can show up multiple times. Some must have data associated with them, others are optional. For example `INTRO` is an optional Tags or Keywords. `INTRO`,  `OUTRO` and `CHAPTER` have text within the square braces this text represents a filename without its extension. The text within `SECTION` or `NAME` if shown would be just text that would be saved to a string within the function that is parsing this file stored into an internal structure within my class. The only key word that can exist within another keyword is `NONE`. For example `NAME[NONE]` would mean that there is no name associated with either the intro, outro, or chapter. Instead it is better to just omit the NAME tag altogether. But is option in the text file for the user who is reading the text file to make their own file of this type.

My class is nearly complete and all I have left to do is create this parsing function and extract and save my data. I have certain rules to follow on this parsing file. Each Keyword with Parameter data are on their own separate line in the text file. But since this file was read in and saved as a string. Here are my questions or concerns.

1. How would I search this stored string and extract what is in between each brace and save it into a sub string, while keeping count of how many times each Key word has shown.
2. Would it be a better solution to instead of reading in all of the contents of this text file into an std::string all at once, and have my parser read in the text line by line until the end and if so how would that be done?

The problem with the Line by line method (my initial approach) is a little harder since I have an external class outside of this class that handles text file streams. It is an inherited class that reads in text, where I have another class that is inherited from the same class as the reader that writes files to text. The parent class is responsible for opening a txt file and saving the text file name with and without path, the inherited class are responsible for closing the file stream that the parent class opens. And since my text file reader only reads in all data at once and saves it to a string this is why I am passing this text file as a string into my parse function.

I also want to keep the structure of this text file format and possibly down the road have the ability to read it in as a binary file as well and have both options. I apologize if this is long, but it is necessary to get my points across. It is more then just getting the subtext from this but also keeping track of repeated keywords and making sure that certain keywords are present while others are optional.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it hard for yourself because you fail to separate concerns.

The main problem you have is just parsing. This is a non-trivial task. Secondary problems are `std::string`, and dealing with the file I/O classes.

Parsing is a well-understood task. It can work perfectly well on any reasonable text representation, including `std::string`. So stop worrying about those problems. Your `void parse(std::string wholeInput)` method should just parse, and do nothing else. It should not care **at all** where that string came from.

Parsing is always doe with a grammar. Sometimes it's done with an explicit grammar, in which case there are quite a few tools which can **generate** the parser for you. But as an exercise, you can still write your own parser.

The first step in parsing is lexing. This breaks down the input in separate tokens. In this case, you seem to have simple lexing rules. A token is (1) a sequence of letters with possibly an underscore, (2) anything between [] or (3) anything between : and the next newline. You can even take a shortcut and treat comments as whitespace, and ignore them in the lexer.

The second step in parsing now gets a nice set of pre-classified tokens. You probably want two functions here, one to recognize the keywords in case (1) and one to get the arguments out of the `[ ]` in case (2).

The third and final step is to do something application-specific with those recognized keywords. I can't give you much advice there, you should know what to do with those keywords and their arguments. But it's of course easy to count them.

Comment: Yes, the overall concepts that you described I understood, but since I am sort of new to parsing text I was having trouble breaking the string down past each key word. I have my key words or tokens saved in a map with an unsigned and a string to use as reference in the search. The problem was getting the information in between the [ ... ] and I was divided on method of either parsing this from a full string or reading in the file and parsing line by line from the filestream.